# GWT- Asynchronous call delay

Tags: gwt, asynchronous

I have a problem with RPC call in GWT.
 Below is an example code snippet:

I have four columns in my UI with effdate and enddate as column header.
The values are not displaying in order. The first column value is displaying in 3rd  column.
most of the time the order changes. Displaying randomly.

I guess the RPC call to the server side method for each count is delayed.
and I found out by debugging the server side method, the effdate and end date that i am     passing for first loop is executing 2nd or 3rd sometimes. It is shuffling.

Can any one help me with this. what changes i need to do in my code to get correct  values displayed in UI.
 Any idea on this?

```
    count=4;
    List finalList = new arrayList();
    for(i=0;i<count;count++)
   {
   effdate= list.get(countincr);
   enddate= list.get(countincr+1);
   //call to server side method to fetch values from DB by passing effdate and end date as    parameter.
   grp.ratecalc(startdate,enddate,new AsyncCallback<List<grVo>>()
  {
  public void onfailure(throwable caught)
  {
  sys.out.print("failure");
  }
  public void onsuccess(List<grVo> result)
 {
 List grpList= new GrpVO();

rate = result.get(0).getrate();
rate1 = result.get(0).getrate1();

grpList.setrate();
grpList.setrate1();

setting values in bean for  the remaining values in the result.

finalList.add(grpList);


if(finalList.size()== count)
{
//calling a method to populate the values
methoddisplay(finalList);

}
}
}
);
countincr+=2;

}  //end of for loop`
```

Comment: Your code could not work. You treat the RCP call synchronic, but infect it is asynchronic. It is undefined which of the four calls will be the first one to recieve a response from the server. You have to redesign your code.

Comment: There is a difference between synchronous & asynchronous call. If you understand that, your problem will be solved.

Comment: Thanks!! I just started using GWT.I understand that once request is made asynchronous calls doesn't wait for the responses. The above code works but the order of display is wrong. How to make it to execute in correct order?  I have to loop many unknown number of Async calls and execute in correct order, how can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a map instead of your `finallist` to keep track of the request and response.
I have made some changes to your code.(Its incomplete. plz make necessary changes).

```
int count=4;
Map<Integer,Object> map = new HashMap<Integer, Object>();
for(int i=0;i<count;count++)
{   final int index=i; 
    effdate= list.get(countincr);
    enddate= list.get(countincr+1);
    grp.ratecalc(startdate,enddate,new AsyncCallback<List<grVo>>()
            {
        public void onfailure(throwable caught) {
            sys.out.print("failure");
        }
        public void onsuccess(List<grVo> result){
            List grpList= new GrpVO();
            rate = result.get(0).getrate();
            rate1 = result.get(0).getrate1();
            grpList.setrate();
            grpList.setrate1();
            map.put(index, grpList);                
            //check all items are put on the map and populate values.
        }
            }
            );
    countincr+=2;
}
```

Here `index` is used to identify the requset and response.
 All the response GrpVO objects are put into the map along with its index.
Finally you have to generate your final list from the map.
Hope this works.